# What is the best way to update/refresh a Page-Mod when you have new data for the 'Include'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, widget, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have a `page-mod` that uses an array as the data for the include field. I want to be able to add/remove data from the array using `splice`, and have the `page-mod`refresh. Here is my code:

```
//APIs:
var store = require("simple-storage");
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
var self = require("self");

//Array for Include:
store.storage.sites = ["*.example.com","*.google.com","*.org"];

//Page-mod code:
myPageMod = pageMod.PageMod({
  include: store.storage.sites,
  contentScriptWhen: 'start',
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("nicEdit-latest.js"),
                      self.data.url("pagedit.js")]
});

//Code to change array
function deleteItem(index) {
  store.storage.sites.splice(index,1);
});
```

Now what I need is a way to update the `page-mod` as part of `deleteItem`, so that it won't apply to the newly deleted sites anymore.

I have tried putting the `page-mod` in a function and calling the function. I also tried updating the array and then `myPageMod.include = store.storage.sites`, but that did nothing as well.

Comment: Would just destroying the page mod and creating a new one every time be acceptable?

Comment: If this is still open, [have a look at the edit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32055963/1587329). You can access `include` just like an array.

Answer (score 2):

`page-mod` has an [`include` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#include), a list of current include rules. You can call `add()` and `remove()` methods on it, e.g.:

```js
function addItem(rule) {
  store.storage.sites.push(rule);
  myPageMod.include.add(rule);
}

function deleteItem(index) {
  myPageMod.include.remove(store.storage.sites.splice(index,1));
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use add() and remove() because then I am treating the `include` list as a different item than the array. I would rather just replace the entire list with the new array.

Comment: OK, I tried it with that code to see what would work, but it still didn't remove the rule. For example, I tried to remove `*.w3schools.com` with it, but it still affected that site.

Comment: @Ian You'll need to send "detach" to the content script which should be listening for that message and clean up the page. Alternatively, refresh all affected pages with something like `myPageMod.tabs.refresh()`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use a variable to reference your pagemod you should be able to change it.

```
var myPageMod = pageMod.PageMod({
  include: store.storage.sites,
  contentScriptWhen: 'start',
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("nicEdit-latest.js"),
                      self.data.url("pagedit.js")]
});

function deleteItem(index) {
  myPageMod.include = store.storage.sites.splice(index,1);
});
```

Comment: Replacing `pageMod.include` with a string (return value of `Array.splice()` is the removed element) certainly won't have the desired effect...

Comment: Why doesn't `store.storage.sites.splice(index,1);` and `myPageMod.include = store.storage.sites;` work?

Comment: @Ian: Why should assigning an array to something that isn't an array do something useful? Long version: if you look at the source code, `pageMod.include` should really be read-only. The only way to manipulate it properly is via `add()` and `remove()` methods (something that you can also learn by reading the documentation).

Comment: @Wladimir The reason I am using an array is because I can store it with `simple-storage`, and it's easy to change it with a content script. This means that my user can which sites are included, and it will remember over each browser session.